Change appearance of highlighted polygons
Updated to 3.34.4-Prizren and when selecting a certain polygon the highlighting has changed to just the points/border going yellow.

How do I change back so that the whole polygon turns solid yellow without adding a solid,transparent filling


Does this answer your question? Apply new style to selected features in QGIS. I wasn't able to reproduce this on v3.36.1: I'm getting the solid yellow for manual selections (Select Features by Polygon) even if I style the layer with Single Symbol>Fill>Simple Fill>Fill style>Dense 7 - which could mean an update would solve this. What's your style definition for this layer and how exactly do you select the polygon?

Selection color

For a project you can change the color and transparency that QGIS uses to indicate that objects are selected. You'll find the setting under: Project Properties | General settings | Selection color. This does not change the style used for the outline of polygons.

From version 3.34 on, you can also change the selection symbol for a specific layer, overriding the project setting. You'll find this setting under: Layer Properties | Rendering | Selections. This setting will allow you to change the line style as well.



Selection color is correct, it's yellow. OP's problem seems to be that the selection keeps the layer's original Fill style of Dense 7, instead of overriding to Solid as it usually does. @Matt I don't seem do have a Rendering tab under Project>Properties on 3.36.1. It seems that those are per-Layer properties which aren't configurable on the global/project level.

@Matt: Great, thanks! QGIS always seems to be a step ahead of me. I added your answer to mine. I think including the project setting makes it more complete. I suggest you copy my answer and paste it as your own (it is your answer after all). My 'answer' can be removed after that. Thanks.

@Zegarek: The project level setting includes the transparency. I forgot to mention that. I changed my answer. Thanks.

@Zegarek My mistake, it is indeed in the layer properties.

@peter, really no need. Your answer is now more complete and you correctly found it in the layer properties when I mistakenly said Project Properties.

@Matt: I tried to find this myself a few times. So the OP is not the only one you helped with this... Thanks
